# Need overflow to be hidden in jquery animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an animation which I want to play within a "container" fixed height and width (herein wanting the overflow to be hidden - everything outside  the black border).

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#animate").animate({width:"120%", top:"45%"}, 400)
    });
```

```css
.container{
  width: 900px;
  height: 980px;
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#animate{
  background: navy;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  height:100px;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div id="animate"></div>
    <div id="animate_b"></div>
    <div id="animate_c"></div>
    <div id="animate_d"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: please provide the HTML and Jquery animation from your code.

Comment: Can you post a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here) with a reproduction? It's hard to answer without seeing your javascript and html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `position: relative;` to the container element's style.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Notice the changes:

1. The `container` now has a relative position, which makes the child absolute positioning binded to it, instead of the `body` or any other parent.
2. I changed the `right` property of `animate` to make it look like what you had.
3. I also changed the `width` percentage in the animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#animate").animate({ width: "170%", top: "45%" }, 400);
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 980px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#animate {
  background: navy;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -250px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="animate"></div>
  <div id="animate_b"></div>
  <div id="animate_c"></div>
  <div id="animate_d"></div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/RwWPoZX)

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#Identifying_the_containing_block):

> If the position property is absolute, the containing block is formed by the edge of the padding box of the nearest ancestor element that has a position value other than static (fixed, absolute, relative, or sticky).